# how to open up a map of a particular city using google APIs in android

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps, android-maps-extensions

I have been able to open up a map of the world through code and mark a few places. However, I always have to zoom down to the city, which takes a little while. Is there any way to directly open up a map of a particular city?

Comment: This may help you [Changing the View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moveCamera](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)) with your last stored location (lat, lng and maybe zoomLevel too) for example.

```
final LatLng location = new LatLng(..., ...);// Loaded from SharedPreferences maybe.

// Move the camera to location with a zoom of 15.
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code to animate the map directly to your city coordinate (lat, lng) and automatically zooming out to specified level :

```
// Set desired lat lng location, and zoom level (for example 10)
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(locationCity.getLatitude(), locationCity.getLongitude()), 10);
// Move the camera to location
gMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```